# Cognito user confirmed have an unconfirmed status

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have successfully implemented Cognito for iOS. I have decided to split the authentication process in 3 phases :

- sign-up
- confirmation with code
- sign-in

For the confirmation with code I have this piece of code :

```
func sendCode() {
    self.pool = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool(forKey: AWSCognitoUserPoolsSignInProviderKey)
    let userForCode = self.pool?.getUser(self.emailTextField.text!)

    // Bizarre ce test ne passe pas pourtant le client est confirmé dans Cognito...
    if (userForCode?.confirmedStatus != AWSCognitoIdentityUserStatus.confirmed) {
        userForCode?.confirmSignUp(confirmCodeTextField.text!, forceAliasCreation: true).continueWith { [weak self] (task) -> Any? in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let error = task.error as? NSError {
                    print("erreurCode : \(error.userInfo["message"])")
                } else if let result = task.result {
                    print("client créé confirmé")
                }
            }
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

I get a user from the userPool and I want to ask the user for is confirmation code if his account is not yet confirmed so the test on userCode.confirmedStatus. Unfortunately, the test is always true even if the user has the confirmed status in the Cognito AWS Console.

Answer (score 0):

I've done the confirmation code in my app, and I did it using `verifyAttribute` after sending an email to the user:

```
self.user?.verifyAttribute("email", code: code).continueWith { (task) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            if let error = task.error as NSError? {
                // handle error (display message perhaps)
            } else {
                // the verification code is correct, continue with your application
            }
        })
        return nil
    }
```

The variable `code` is taken from the textField where the user enters his verification code.